# Existence of a harmonic function with prescribed values at the center and 4 boundary points

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

On a disk $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is the with middle point $(0,0)$ and radius 1. Is there a harmonic function such that:
$u(0,0) = −1, u(1,0) = 3, u(0,1) = 6, u(−1,0) = 2, u(0,−1) = 7$ ?

I think the answer is yes. But how can I argue it riguously but easily? Using Poisson kernel? The I have to find such function $f(e^{2\pi it})$ taking values 3, 6, 2, 7 at some points and whose integral is -1.

Comment: Note that harmonic functions satisfy the mean value property, so the average of $u$ on the boundary will have to be $-1$.

Comment: Does the boundary condition need to be smooth or even analytic?

Comment: Perhaps you can use the formula of interpolation: for $n\geq 1$, $a_k$ distincts, and $b_k$, the polynomial
$$P(z)=\sum_{k=1}^n b_k\prod_{j\not =k}(z-a_j)/\prod_{j\not =k}(a_k-a_j)$$ is a polynomial with $P(a_k)=b_k$ for all $k$. Take $a_1=0,a_2=1,a_3=i,a_4=-1,a_5=-i$, with the values indicated, the real part of such $P(x+iy)$ is a solution.

Comment: I think the boundary condition only needs to be continuous for a solution to exist in a region and on its boundary;  and if the boundary function is discontinuous, then the BCs are satisfied everywhere except the discontinuity points.  But it's pretty easy to construct an analytic function with the desired properties via a (finite) Fourier series.

Comment: "Is there a harmonic function" Defined where?

Comment: But if the boundary condition is just not continuous, then isn't there a problem to be even differentiable at the point of the boundary?

Answer (score 2):

Kelenner's suggest is probably the quickest way to handle the problem:  let $u$ be the real part of the interpolating polynomial $P$ with given data:
$$P(0)=-1, \ P(1)=3, \ P(i) = 6, \ P(-1) = 2, \ P(-i) = 7$$
[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolate++%5B0,+-1%5D,+%5B1,+3%5D,+%5Bi,+6%5D,+%5B-1,+2%5D,+%5B-i,+7%5D) gives 
$$
P(z) = \frac14(22z^4 +(1-i)z^3 -8z^2  + (1+i)z  -4) 
$$
which is easily seen to have the required values, so $u=\operatorname{Re} P$ is a harmonic function with the given conditions.